# Custom UIImageView in UITableViewCell being cut off in subsequent cells - Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiimageview

[UITableViewCell Custom UIImageView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5tcQ.jpg)

Image:
  [Custom TableViewCell UIImageView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5tcQ.jpg)

If you click on the link above, you'll see that after the first row, the custom UIImageView is being cut off horizontally and then vertically in subsequent rows. Any ideas on how to fix this?

In viewDidLoad I changes row heights as follows:

```
// Set cell row height
self.tableView.rowHeight = 60
```

Here's the code for the TableView:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    var count = Int()

    if self.names.count != 0 {

        count = self.names.count

    } else if self.names.count == 0 {

        count = 1

    }

    return count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell : UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    for view in cell.contentView.subviews {
        // Clear subviews
        view.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    // Customize separator width
    tableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false

    // Create imageView
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(10, 5, 50, 50))
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 25
    imageView.clipsToBounds = true
    cell.contentView.addSubview(imageView)

    // Create textLabel
    let textLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(70, 10, self.view.frame.width, 20))
    textLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 15.0)
    textLabel.textAlignment = .Left
    cell.contentView.addSubview(textLabel)

    // Create lastMessageLabel
    let lastMessageLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(70, 30, self.view.frame.width, 20))
    lastMessageLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 12)
    lastMessageLabel.textAlignment = .Left
    lastMessageLabel.textColor = UIColor.grayColor()
    cell.contentView.addSubview(lastMessageLabel)

    if self.names.count != 0 {
        // Add contact cell
        imageView.image = self.images[indexPath.row]
        textLabel.text = self.names[indexPath.row] as? String
        lastMessageLabel.text = self.lastMessage[indexPath.row] as? String

    }

    if self.names.count == 0 {
        // Add warning
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "user-placeholder.png")
        textLabel.text = "No users saved :("
        lastMessageLabel.text = "Tap the search tab to find users."

    }

    return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if self.names.count != 0 {
        print(self.names.count)
        print(self.names[indexPath.row])
        print(self.ids[indexPath.row])
        self.selectedUserName = self.names[indexPath.row] as! String
        self.selectedUserId = self.ids[indexPath.row] as! String
        self.selectedUserImage = self.images[indexPath.row]
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("chat", sender: self)

    }

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete && self.userRef.savedUsers.count != 0 {

        startActivityIndicator()

        let savedUsers = NSMutableArray()

        for user in self.userRef.savedUsers {

            if user as! String != self.userRef.savedUsers[indexPath.row] as! String {

                savedUsers.addObject(user as! String)

            }

        }

        self.rootRef.child("users").child((FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid)!).child("savedUsers").setValue(savedUsers, withCompletionBlock: { (error: NSError?, FIRDatabaseReference: FIRDatabaseReference) -> Void in

            if error == nil {

                print("deleted: \(self.userRef.savedUsers[indexPath.row])")

                // Remove user
                self.userRef.savedUsers.removeObject(self.userRef.savedUsers[indexPath.row])
                self.names.removeObjectAtIndex(indexPath.row)
                self.images.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
                self.lastMessage.removeObjectAtIndex(indexPath.row)

                self.stopActivityIndicator()
                self.loadUsers()
                self.displayAlert("Contact Deleted", message: "The user has been removed from your contacts.")

            } else {

                self.stopActivityIndicator()
                self.displayAlert("Delete Failed", message: "Please try again later.")

            }
        })
    }

}
```

EDIT:

The problem was `imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit` which needed to be `.ScaleAspectFill`

Comment: Great question. Perfect. /sarcasim

Comment: I submitted the question before finishing by accident. My bad. I would appreciate help now that its updated!

Comment: no problem. I changed my vote. If I have time later(tomorrow, almost 1:00am here) and the question is not answered ill have a bash. Good luck.

Comment: Just a quick comment. Why don't you use storyboard to create the layouts? Just drag and drop and Bobs yer uncle. It really is a lot easier. Less code to maintain down the road etc.

Comment: That's a good point. I started like that and I'm not the biggest fan. I'll do it programmatically this time around just to learn, but I'll definitely keep that in mind next time.